# pyplot static color colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the following code to generate a pyplot with a colormap:

```
# Create a 3d plot
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Plot the frequency-time
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=4, cstride=5 + (samplerate / 20), alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=tlen, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

However I would like to use a colormap with a static color: #066. So no gradient effect.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Greetings,
Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a constant color don't pass the `cmap` parameter, use the `colors` instead:

```
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=tlen, colors='r')
```

Comment: If you came to this question from Google, looking for a fixed-scale cmap with `imshow`, you'll want to use e.g. `plt.imshow(..., cmap=cmap, vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0)`.